# adding different possibilities in xskak looping

Tags: chess

I would like to add different possibilities to continue a game using xskak looping. I used the following code which starts the game from the beginning in each possibility instead of continuing from the last move of the original game. How can this be done?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xskak, chessboard}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\makeatletter
\providecommand\xskak@beforecomment{} %ups a bug, definition is missing
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\newcommand\getmovestyle[1]{%
\ifthenelse
  {\equal{#1}{N}}%knight move
  {\def\mymovestyle{[clockwise=false,style=knight]curvemove}}%
  {\ifthenelse
    {\equal{#1}{}}% castling
    {\def\mymovestyle{curvemove}}%
    {\def\mymovestyle{straightmove}}}}%

\begin{center}
\newchessgame %don't add math here  \[\newchessgame\].  no need for \newchessgame\longmoves
\hidemoves{
1. d4 e6 2. e4 d5 3. Nc3 c5 4. Nf3 Nc6 5. exd5 exd5 6. Be2 Nf6 7. O-O Be7 8. Bg5 O-O 9. dxc5 Be6 10. Nd4 Bxc5 11. Nxe6 fxe6 12. Bg4 Qd6 13. Bh3 Rae8 14. Qd2 Bb4 15. Bxf6 Rxf6 16. Rad1 Qc5 17. Qe2 Bxc3 18. bxc3 Qxc3 19. Rxd5 Nd4 20. Qh5 Ref8 21. Re5 Rh6 22. Qg5  Rxh3 23. Rc5 
Qg3 \xskakcomment{white was offered the Queen in three ways, and he could not accept it by any means, else white would face an inevitable mate. white resigned. Qg3 was indeed one of the best moves ever played.}
}% do not leave an empty line before this closing }
\xskakloop{%
\getmovestyle{\xskakget{piecechar}}%
\chessboard[normalboard,% do not use \[\chessboard[ ]\]
 pgfstyle=\mymovestyle, color=blue!50,
  markmoves=\xskakget{move}, pgfshortenend=0.3em, arrow=to,     coloremph, color=red!50, markstyle=circle, markfield=\xskakget{movefrom},
  emphfields=\xskakget{moveto}, setfen=\xskakget{nextfen}]\\
  \xskakget{opennr}%print the move number
  \xskakget{lan} %print the move
  \xskakget{nag} % print the comment
  \par           % new paragraph 
  }% End of \xskakloop...

\storegame{game1}% to store game to memory

\restoregame{game1}% to restore game from memory
\hidemoves{
24. Qxg3  \xskakcomment{Possibility1}
Ne2+ 25. Kh1 Nxg3+ 26. Kg1 Nxf1 27. gxh3 
}% do not leave an empty line before this closing }
\xskakloop{%
\getmovestyle{\xskakget{piecechar}}%
\chessboard[normalboard,% do not use \[\chessboard[ ]\]
 pgfstyle=\mymovestyle, color=blue!50,
  markmoves=\xskakget{move}, pgfshortenend=0.3em, arrow=to,     coloremph, color=red!50, markstyle=circle, markfield=\xskakget{movefrom},
  emphfields=\xskakget{moveto}, setfen=\xskakget{nextfen}]\\
  \xskakget{opennr}%print the move number
  \xskakget{lan} %print the move
  \xskakget{nag} % print the comment
  \par           % new paragraph 
  }% End of \xskakloop...

\restoregame{game1}% to restore game from memory
\hidemoves{
24. hxg3  \xskakcomment{Possibility2}
Ne2# 
}% do not leave an empty line before this closing }
\xskakloop{%
\getmovestyle{\xskakget{piecechar}}%
\chessboard[normalboard,% do not use \[\chessboard[ ]\]
 pgfstyle=\mymovestyle, color=blue!50,
  markmoves=\xskakget{move}, pgfshortenend=0.3em, arrow=to,     coloremph, color=red!50, markstyle=circle, markfield=\xskakget{movefrom},
  emphfields=\xskakget{moveto}, setfen=\xskakget{nextfen}]\\
  \xskakget{opennr}%print the move number
  \xskakget{lan} %print the move
  \xskakget{nag} % print the comment
  \par           % new paragraph 
  }% End of \xskakloop...

\restoregame{game1}% to restore game from memory
\hidemoves{
24. fxg3  \xskakcomment{Possibility3}
Ne2+ 25. Kh1 Rxf1# 
}% do not leave an empty line before this closing }
\xskakloop{%
\getmovestyle{\xskakget{piecechar}}%
\chessboard[normalboard,% do not use \[\chessboard[ ]\]
 pgfstyle=\mymovestyle, color=blue!50,
  markmoves=\xskakget{move}, pgfshortenend=0.3em, arrow=to,     coloremph, color=red!50, markstyle=circle, markfield=\xskakget{movefrom},
  emphfields=\xskakget{moveto}, setfen=\xskakget{nextfen}]\\
  \xskakget{opennr}%print the move number
  \xskakget{lan} %print the move
  \xskakget{nag} % print the comment
  \par           % new paragraph 
  }% End of \xskakloop...

\restoregame{game1}% to restore game from memory
\hidemoves{
24. Qxg3  \xskakcomment{Possibility4}
Ne2+ 25. Kh1 Nxg3+ 26. fxg3 Rxf1# 
}% do not leave an empty line before this closing }
\xskakloop{%
\getmovestyle{\xskakget{piecechar}}%
\chessboard[normalboard,% do not use \[\chessboard[ ]\]
 pgfstyle=\mymovestyle, color=blue!50,
  markmoves=\xskakget{move}, pgfshortenend=0.3em, arrow=to,     coloremph, color=red!50, markstyle=circle, markfield=\xskakget{movefrom},
  emphfields=\xskakget{moveto}, setfen=\xskakget{nextfen}]\\
  \xskakget{opennr}%print the move number
  \xskakget{lan} %print the move
  \xskakget{nag} % print the comment
  \par           % new paragraph 
  }% End of \xskakloop...
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You shouldn't make examples that creates over 200 pages.  Minimalize them first to the core of your problem.

Comment: That was the problem. But I have to post the whole code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can restrict the loop with the keys initmoveid and stopmoveid.

You can also start a new game with the fen and the moveid from another.

```
\documentclass[parskip=half-,landscape]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xskak}
\usepackage{chessboard}

\makeatletter
\providecommand\xskak@beforecomment{} %ups a bug, definition is missing
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\newchessgame[id=Main] % main game
\hidemoves{1. d4 e6 2. e4 d5 3. Nc3 c5 4. Nf3 Nc6 5. exd5 exd5 6. Be2 Nf6 7. O-O Be7 8. Bg5 O-O 9. dxc5 Be6 10. Nd4 Bxc5 11. Nxe6 fxe6 12. Bg4 Qd6 13. Bh3 Rae8 14. Qd2 Bb4 15. Bxf6 Rxf6 16. Rad1 Qc5 17. Qe2 Bxc3 18. bxc3 Qxc3 19. Rxd5 Nd4 20. Qh5 Ref8 21. Re5 Rh6 22. Qg5  Rxh3 23. Rc5 Qg3} 


\minisec{Variation 1}

\newchessgame[id=var,  %var
  setfen=\XskakMainlastfen, %fen from Main
  moveid=\XskakMainnextmoveid
 ]
\hidemoves{24. Qxg3  \xskakcomment{Possibility1}
Ne2+ 25. Kh1 Nxg3+ 26. Kg1 Nxf1 27. gxh3}

\xskakloop[initmoveid=24w,stopmoveid=25b]{% restrict the loop
 \begin{tabular}{c}
 \chessboard[tinyboard,setfen=\xskakget{nextfen}]\\
  \xskakget{opennr}%print the move number
  \xskakget{lan} %print the move
  \xskakget{nag} % print the comment
 \end{tabular}
  \quad 
  }%


\minisec{Variation 2}

\newchessgame[id=var,  %var
  setfen=\XskakMainlastfen,
  moveid=\XskakMainnextmoveid
 ]
\hidemoves{24. hxg3  \xskakcomment{Possibility2} Ne2# }

\xskakloop{%
\begin{tabular}{c}
 \chessboard[tinyboard,setfen=\xskakget{nextfen}]\\
  \xskakget{opennr}%print the move number
  \xskakget{lan} %print the move
  \xskakget{nag} % print the comment
\end{tabular}  
  \quad 
  }%


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I got an error message

The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used. Check that the command is spelled correctly.

 from lines
\minisec{Variation 1}

\minisec{Variation 2}

Comment: I am using the Beamer class. The compiled file starts with the first move of possibility 1, and the line Variation 2 appears with the last move of possibility 1

Comment: The beamer class is not really sensible to test this things. It creates many pages and it is a rather special class with lots of grouping  and unusual code which can disturb the loops and commands. Learn first how to use xskak in a normal standard class and convert the code to beamer in a second step. Btw: you are not using beamer correctly -- contents should be in frames and slides.

Comment: I can manage the Beamer class, and with your previous precious help for my questions, I could create the file which link is in the end of this comment. I just want to add different possibilities to continue the game, if this is possible. Thank you for your patience. my file url is:  http://pc.cd/Ef67

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the idea of using  setfen to store the last position of the game, then restorefen and adding the new possibility. This is repeated for every other possibility. I used the following code:

```
\chessboard[setfen=,storefen=XX]
\newchessgame[restorefen=XX]
\hidemoves{1.hxg3  Ne2#}
```